# Hmac256 Signature invalid error Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to retrieve trades from a service called 3Commas in Google Apps Script. I've worked with public endpoints before, but this is the first time I've attempted to work with signed endpoints. I'm currently receiving an error that states:

```
[19-01-09 16:46:24:592 EST] {"error":"signature_invalid","error_description":"Provided signature is invalid"}
```

I'm guessing this is a formatting issue on my part. I'm using [jsSHA](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/blob/master/src/sha256.js) to build the HMAC part. I've tried following the example in the docs. But I haven't quite got it yet. Any suggestions on what it could be?

3Commas Docs: https://github.com/3commas-io/3commas-official-api-docs#signed--endpoint-security

```
function main() {
  var key = 'apikey';
  var secret = 'apisecret';

  var baseUrl = "https://3commas.io/public/api";
  var endPoint = "/ver1/smart_trades";
  var pointParams = "?limit=10&offset=&account_id=&scope=&type="
  //base url + end point + params
  var queryString = baseUrl+endPoint+pointParams;

  var message = queryString;
  var secret = secret;
  var shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-256", "TEXT");
  shaObj.setHMACKey(secret, "B64");
  shaObj.update(message);
  var signature = shaObj.getHMAC("B64");

  //headers
  var hparams = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {'APIKEY': key,
                'Signature': signature},
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  //call
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryString , hparams).getContentText();
  Logger.log(data)
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [3Commas Docs](https://github.com/3commas-io/3commas-official-api-docs#signed--endpoint-security) in your question, I propose the modification points as follows.

#### Modification points:

- It seems that the value which is required to encrypt is after `https://3commas.io`.
- You can encrypt the values using the method of `computeHmacSha256Signature()` in Class Utilities of GAS. In this case, jsSHA is not required to be used.

  - But when `computeHmacSha256Signature()` is used, the value becomes the bytes array of the signed hexadecimal. So it is required to convert it to the unsigned hexadecimal.

#### Modified script:

```
function main() {
  var key = 'apikey';
  var secret = 'apisecret';

  var baseUrl = "https://3commas.io"; // Modified
  var endPoint = "/public/api/ver1/smart_trades"; // Modified
  var pointParams = "?limit=10&offset=&account_id=&scope=&type="; // or "?limit=10"
  var queryString = endPoint + pointParams; // Modified
  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(queryString, secret); // Added
  signature = signature.map(function(e) {return ("0" + (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");  // Added

  //headers
  var hparams = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {'APIKEY': key,
                'Signature': signature},
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  //call
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + queryString , hparams).getContentText(); // Modified
  Logger.log(data)
}
```

#### Note:

- About `var pointParams = "?limit=10&offset=&account_id=&scope=&type="`, in the case of the endpoint you use, limit, offset, account_id, scope and type are no mandatory. So it might be `var pointParams = "?limit=10"`. If the error occurs, please try it.

#### References:

- [computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsha256signaturevalue-key_4)
- [Public Rest API for 3commas.io (2018-10-26)](https://github.com/3commas-io/3commas-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md)

  - This document is more detail.

Comment: That did the trick! Ironically I had the utilities signature method in before, but I didn't think I had the unsigned portion correct so I switched to jsSHA. Also an interesting note. I was curious and made the identical changes to my old code still using jsSHA and it still returned the error even with the changes to the URL/endpoints. So thank you! That would have taken me even longer to try and figure out. (I can't give rep yet, sorry!)

Comment: @Phil Thank you for replying. If you have any questions, feel free to tell me. I would like to study too.